# How to use Regex for Static HTML code (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I am new to Regualr Expressions, and I am just not getting the hang of it yet.

I have grabbed html content from a given webpage using CURL and PHP. This webpage **never** changes its structure. The results on the page are dependant on a search function, but the html tags are always the same. I need to grab the resulting data from the page depending on what search terms were entered.

The data I need is:

`<h1 class="location_only">(555) 555-5555 is a Landline</h1>`

So I need to grab whatever is inbetween

`<h1 class="location_only">` and `</h1>`

If I have `$data`, which is the resulting HTML, how do I put that into a regular expression and echo the data I find as `$result`?

Comment: Can you provide an example or snippet of the html code you're trying to extract from?

Comment: answered millions times where ... parse the html as xml and take it from there ... don't use regex

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why did it delete my code? I put an example in the original question????

Comment: @user1351759: There's a particular syntax for code. An edit should turn up soon.

Comment: If you're dealing with a HTML document, use a HTML parser. If you just have a string with few `<` and `>` then RegEx is fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Please do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Please use an HTML Parser, such as [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).  Your problem may seem localized, but it is not.  Even if it was, there is a great affinity for problems of this type to grow in scope at a later date which will cause you a massive headache even if you could get it to work with Regular expressions.

Comment: Well I have Simple HTML DOM Parser, but I really don't know how to use it in this application. If I did, I would. Can you direct me to a tutorial on that or should I start a new question?

Answer (score 1):

You can select text between tags with this search pattern:

```
<span id="result1">(.*?)</span>
```

Capture group returns "(555) 555-5555 is a Landline" if your code is: `<span id="result1">(555) 555-5555 is a Landline</span>`.

See [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for further info how to echo the result.

Also look into HTML DOM Parser like suggested by others. Maybe I shouldn't have answered at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably extract information from HTML with a regex.  You can, however, use an HTML parser, like [DOMDocument::LoadHTML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).  This will take your HTML from a string and then you can use functions like [getElementById](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) or [getElementByTagName](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to find your values.  There are other HTML parsers out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both 2 answers telling you not to Regex and instead use a DOM parser are correct, however, if the structure of the page doesn't change, a quick & dirty regex will do the trick just fine, given that you have absolutely well placed start and ending point for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You've been cautioned enough to **not to use regex to parse HTML**. So here is a DOM parser based code to extract your value:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1 class="location_only">(555) 555-5555 is a Landline</H1>
</body>
</html>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$value = $xpath->evaluate("string(//h1[@class='location_only']/text())"); 
echo "Your H1 Value=[$value]\n"; // prints text between <h1> and </h1>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Your H1 Value=[(555) 555-5555 is a Landline]
```